# String concatenation in procedure parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to do something like this:

```
declare @var varchar(50) = '2';
exec sp_myprocedure 'first', 'sec ' + @var
```

but I get an error:

```
Incorrect syntax near '+'.
```

Of course I can set variable before exec procedure:

```
set @var = 'sec ' + @var;
```

but I don't want this, because I have many execution in my code and I don't want create million variables.

Comment: have you tried, `exec sp_myprocedure 'first', ('sec ' + @var)`?

Comment: @JW: I tried that and it's don't work (also give same error)

Comment: So you want a way for SQL Server to forgive illegal syntax that shouldn't have been written in the first place?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to fix your code, sorry. There is no magic that will make this legal:

```
EXEC dbo.procedure_name @var + 'constant';
```

Also, [**STOP** using the `sp_` prefix for stored procedures](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix).

Answer (score 11):

I think it's not possible to use string concatenation in procedure execution if you're using `EXEC`.

From [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx):

> Execute a stored procedure or function
>
> [ { EXEC | EXECUTE } ]
>
> > ```
> > { 
> >   [ @return_status = ]
> >   { module_name [ ;number ] | @module_name_var } 
> >     [ [ @parameter = ] { value 
> >                        | @variable [ OUTPUT ] 
> >                        | [ DEFAULT ] 
> >                        }
> >     ]
> >   [ ,...n ]
> >   [ WITH <execute_option> [ ,...n ] ]
> > } [;]
> > ```

The `@parameter` must be a **value**.
But this: `'sec ' + @var` is an **[expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190286.aspx)**.

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to declare a million variables, you simply need to declare a single variable, and set it prior to each `EXEC`:

```
DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(max) = '';

declare @var varchar(50) = '2';

set @cmd = 'sec ' + @var;
exec sp_myprocedure 'first', @cmd

set @cmd = 'try ' + @var;
exec sp_myprocedure 'first', @cmd

set @cmd = 'foo ' + @var;
exec sp_myprocedure 'first', @cmd

set @cmd = 'bar ' + @var;
exec sp_myprocedure 'first', @cmd
```